# Launching a new Android activity via Javascript in a Webview

Tags: android, webview

I have android test app and I am trying to call a function with my JavacriptInterface class. This webview plays a video and when it ends it calls a JS method which should call the android method to launch a new activity.

That doesn't seem to be happening at all, when the video is done it's like the webview reloads and it plays the video again.

Is it possible to launch an activity like this? I can provideo sample code in about 45 minutes.

The VideoActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    getActionBar().hide();
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    try
    {
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        });
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        Intent i = new Intent("com.example.myapplication.BlankActivity");
        myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this,i), "Android");
        myWebView.loadUrl("url");
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        String msg = e.getMessage();
        String trace = e.getStackTrace().toString();
    }


}

public class JavaScriptInterface {
    Context mContext;
    Intent i;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    JavaScriptInterface(Context c, Intent i) {
        mContext = c;
        this.i = i;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    public void onComplete(String toast) {
        startActivity(i);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

BlankActivity.java

```
public class BlankActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_blank);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.blank, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Here's my Javascript code on the page the webview runs when the video is done.

```
function onComplete() {
    Android.onComplete();
}
```

as

Comment: Show the applicable code, it will be easier to identify where the issue is.

Comment: Hey RGraham, thanks for the response I have added the sample code. If you need anything else, I will post it.